# Change Git user in terminal

Tags: git, remote, github

I am trying to push some commits in a repo as a collaborator. But once I push the commit, Git throws an error where it shows the push was trying to do with my old account which is not authorized for this repo. I set up my new user but Git is using my old account.

I set up my credentials using git config but the result is the same.

git config --list result:
[image: git config --list result]

Comment: What is the output if you do `git config --global --list`?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to retain the user.email from your current config run

```
git config --global user.email 'your.email@example.com'
```